# Stuck Pushing to /sdcard/autodeploy.zip

Tags: nexus-7

Currently attempting to install on my 4.2.2 Nexus 7 but the installer is stuck at Pushing /home/david/Downloads/phablet-flash/95/quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip to /sdcard/autodeploy.zip

What can I do to get past this/make it work basically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's copying a 500MB file over to your sdcard and it takes a while.  You can open up android terminal emulator and do an 'ls -la /sdcard/autodeploy.zip' to see how much has been copied over.