# Timeframe on push to autodeploy.zip?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Given the answer to this question ([Stuck Pushing to /sdcard/autodeploy.zip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259526/stuck-pushing-to-sdcard-autodeploy-zip)) how long should one expect the push to take given standard USB?

I'm attempting the flash via a pretty hefty Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows 7, and it's taking a long while. Over a half-hour at this point.

Answer (score 0):

connected my N7 (running ubuntu touch) to my pc (Ubuntu 12.10, no virtual machine)

```
    2:35 started phablet-flash on my pc
    2:35 downloads 'quantal-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip" and the md5sum
    2:36 pushing grouper.zip to /sdcard: 1145 KB/s  (56481865 bytes in 48.145s)
    2:37 pushing quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip to sdcard: 1129 KB/s (504219641 bytes in 436.014s)
    2:44 N7 reboots
    2:44 Android Logo with "open belly"
    2:47 done Ubuntu Touch up and running
```

My suggestion: If possible, try it on a plain Ubuntu and not on a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did eventually work when I used a file manager to keep checking on the file. Maybe some defiance of the "watched pot never boils" standard.